# Java Reflection - Methods Introspection

Tags: java, reflection

```
Method[] theMethods = myClass.getMethods();
for( Method m : theMethods ){
...

}
```

Will the array include all the methods of the class? public, private, protected and all inherited?
Will I have access to all of them mainly the private and protected ones?

If not, how can I get all the methods of a class and also have access to all?

Comment: -1 for a question answerable by reading the javadoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all methods of a class you need to recursively call getDeclaredMethods() on the class and all it's superclasses. Depending on what you want to achive with it you might need to remove duplicates which can occur due to method overloading.

Comment: So getMethods() + getDeclaredMethods() - declared public methods in the calss = all the class methods?

Comment: `getMethods() + getDeclaredMethods()` gives you all public methods and private+protected that are implemented in the class directly but not the private and protected methods that of it's superclasses.

Answer (score 4):

The [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) makes this pretty clear:

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the public member methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including those declared by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces.

To get at non-public methods, use [`getDeclaredMethods`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

From the [API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29):

> Returns an array containing Method
>   objects reflecting all the public
>   member methods of the class or
>   interface represented by this Class
>   object, including those declared by
>   the class or interface and those
>   inherited from superclasses and
>   superinterfaces.

So it gets you only public methods. To get all methods, you have to use `getDeclaredMethods()` on the class and all its superclasses (via `getSuperclass()`).

In order to call non-public methods, you can use `setAccessible(true)` on the `Method` object (if the security manager allows it).